# .htaccess returns me blank page?

Tags: php, html, css, .htaccess

I have styles,images,data from database included in my index.php

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)-v-([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*) ?hteam=$1&ateam=$2&league=$3&id=$4 [NC]
```

when i type this:
/vasco-v-avai/brazil-série-a/2l1o4

it returns me blank page, even i have completed styles?

When i check source code of page, there is just head,body and some divs that are not displayed on page...

When i do this, to echo current match:

```
if(isset($_GET['hteam'])){
        echo $_GET['hteam'] . ' - ' . $_GET['ateam'];
    }
```

I get normally

> vasco - avai

But with no style.

Comment: Did you try this without rewrite? Just to see, if this works with parameters.

Comment: without RewriteRule or without .htaccess? Style without .htaccess is there, without RewriteRule is Internal Server Error.

Comment: Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on is before RewriteRule

Comment: Try adding this in the `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />`

Comment: Ah SOLVED!
Problem was that my query for leagues had "Coutnry" instead "Country", but it was blank because errors was turned off, now when i turn on error_reporting i saw exception... Sorry...